# DATE_FORMAT in PHP query from MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, select, date-format

I need to select a date type field through a PHP query. The problem suggests when I try to modify the value to the type d-m-Y. I need to format this data to show it in a graph using AJAX.

If I make the query in Heidi, it works perfectly but if I try it through PHP I get the following error:

MySQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total, DATE_FORMAT(login_at, '%d-%m-%Y') as datee FROM connections
    WHERE login_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
    GROUP BY datee;
```

PHP query:

//query to get data from the table

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id) as total, login_at as datee
FROM connections
    WHERE login_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
    GROUP BY datee;");
```

//execute query

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

//loop through the returned data

```
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

//now print the data

```
print json_encode($data);
```

Error:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  sprintf(): Too few arguments in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\chartjs-master\php-mysql-chartjs\data.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::query(): Empty query in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\chartjs-master\php-mysql-chartjs\data.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\chartjs-master\php-mysql-chartjs\data.php</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function close() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\chartjs-master\php-mysql-chartjs\data.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\chartjs-master\php-mysql-chartjs\data.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />
```

I have searched and tried each and every one of the solutions that I have found on the internet but without any success.

Comment: No need to use sprintf to build your query: 1) You're not passing any parameters in, and 2) it's not a good idea even if you had. Prepared statements are the way to go. Remove the sprintf and just run that query, and the rest *should* clear up. You're also never passing in the date_format in your PHP query, so that wouldn't affect anything.

Comment: This `sprintf` is a sign of some extremely dangerous habits. That function should be nowhere near your queries, it's how [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) happen. It's very important to use *prepared statements with placeholder values* to introduce data because that will properly encode the values and **never** `sprintf` which does zero escaping.